# Fast Reports Website Banned?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, hyperlinks

The comment is deleted now, but in [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006843/delphi-exe-after-build-error?noredirect=1#comment28082043_19006843), someone commented with [a link to a page](http://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?s=0ca83b2e72fea8e4a8109c921550eb34&showtopic=10098&mode=threaded&pid=27648), but changed `.com` to `.xxx` and explained that `.xxx` had to be changed to `.com` - because that website is banned by Stack Overflow.

Why would this site be banned from linking?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been in our blacklist since April 30, 2011 due to *rampant* spam. We strongly resist adding URLs or entire domains to the list that could have a legitimate use on the site. Unfortunately, we had little choice.

For that to be removed, they'd need to [get in touch](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) with us and offer some assurance that it's not going to happen again.

Comment: It's sad they would ruin their reputation like that, especially since Fast Reports come with most of the latest versions of Delphi - pre-installed... Why would they spam?

Comment: @JerryDodge _They_ may not have, they could have hired a SEO / Marketing firm that did this without their knowledge. Believe it or not, that's not uncommon. If I can talk to a verifiable human being over there, I'm happy to take it out. I just need to know that it _stopped_ and won't start again.

Comment: I've faced the exact same thing in the software company I work for. We hired a marketing person to do SEO, and did some really crazy and dumb stunts, including something that resulted in an old customer of ours finding themselves in a Google search, in a page published on our website (which he managed), with information about what they bought, when they bought it, and how much they paid for it. So, the world could see not only every sale we've done, but our customer info, item info, and the prices... I'm the one who had to do some research to discover this mistake

Comment: @JerryDodge Indeed, it is sad. I've seen some halfway decent products/services earn themselves ugly reputations here due to someone going crazy on their behalf like this.

Answer (score 14):

The only way websites can be banned is when they are manually entered into the blacklist by an SE employee. For URLs pretty much the only reason this happens is if the URL is part of a lot of spam posts.

Comment: This. There are 3 pages of deleted answers with links to Fast Reports that were all posted by 3 users.  I wonder where they work.

Comment: @Bill - was the deleted comment also by one of those three users?

Comment: @AdamRackis Actually no, that user is a very common user in the Delphi community named `TLama`

Comment: @AdamRackis Those three accounts were deleted too.